# Non-blocking pipes in UNIX

Tags: linux, system-calls

### Idea

This script doesn't work:

```bash
mkfifo pipe
echo Hello! > pipe
cat pipe # unreachable
```

...Because `echo` waits for someone to read from `pipe` before doing anything.

If there were space "inside" the pipe to store `Hello!`, then `echo` could exit and `cat` could read from the pipe. We could accomplish this if `pipe` were a normal file, but then there wouldn't be a way to limit its size.

### Analogy

In Go, channels act like pipes. We can add a buffer which will store some number of values at a time:

```golang
...

func main() {
  // channel has a "buffer", which stores up to 1 message
  channel := make(chan *byte, 1)
  
  write("Hello!", channel)
  read(channel, fmt.Println)
}
```

Comment: What has Go have to do with Unix pipes? That's a completely different thing.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli The go programming language allows you to make _channels_, which are basically pipes for functions in your go program. Here I'm comparing go's channel buffering feature to Unix fifo files.

Comment: Why downvote? I simply asked a question about something that cannot be done and got the answer I was looking for.

Comment: Hmm, maybe you could add an actual question in your "Proposal" section. As it currently stands, there seems to be no actual question asked, and it seems to need additional clarification, which is why somebody could have downvoted it.

Comment: There isn't a "suggestion" section. Stack Overflow is a Questions & Answers website. I've edited your post to make it clearer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231718/discussion-between-stackoverflowuser-and-marco-bonelli).

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Please explain how to move my post to the "proposal" section... Thanks

Comment: Maybe I was unclear: I was *not* telling you to move your post anywhere. I was telling you to edit the text after `## Proposal` in your post. I already did that for you. No further action is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure if this satisfies your criteria, but it seems to be an effective work-around:

```
$ ( : < fifo & ); ( echo 'Hello!' > fifo & )
$ cat fifo
Hello!
```

The basic idea is to open a reader (which does not consume any data) so the the `echo` can write data into the pipe.  (The parentheses are just to suppress the job control output and can be omitted.)

It may be clearer to use:

```
$ sleep 1 < fifo &  echo 'Hello!' > fifo 
[1] 70954
$ sed 1q fifo
Hello!
[1]+  Done                    sleep 1 < fifo
$
```

But there's a bit of a race condition.  If the `sleep` terminates before `echo` runs (unlikely), then the `echo` will hang.  It's safer to run `echo` in the background.

Comment: The first line terminates immediately, causing the second line to hang and wait as normal for pipe input... Useful, but needs revision. +1

Answer (score 2):

> pipes are blocking and must have a receiving end to be written to. I believe this is because pipes don't have any memory allocated to them and can't store information between reading and writing.

You are almost correct here. Named pipes are blocking, and need both a reader and a writer that have the pipe open *at the same time* to work. There actually is a buffer that is managed by the kernel behind a pipe, but the whole operation is transparent to the user programs. The buffer is only created *after* two processes have opened the pipe (one for writing and one for reading).

So in your example, here:

```sh
mkfifo pipe
echo Hello! > pipe
```

The `echo` program would be stuck waiting to `open()` the pipe with `O_WRONLY`, as the `open` syscall blocks on a FIFO until some other process opens the same FIFO for reading. The FIFO also cannot be opened in a non-blocking way, as `man 2 open` specifies:

```
ERRORS

[...]

       ENXIO  O_NONBLOCK | O_WRONLY is set, the named file is a FIFO,
              and no process has the FIFO open for reading.
```

You can see this yourself by running the above command in a shell and noticing that it hangs indefinitely. If you then open another shell and `cat` from the pipe the `echo` on the other shell will succesfully open and write to the pipe and `cat` will read what was written to it.

You will *not* be able to successfully open a FIFO for writing before someone else opens it for reading. This is by design.

---

To make an analogous example to your Go one, that would be something like:

```golang
go write()
go read()
```

Note: this is just a mere analogy, I don't have much experience in Go.

Comment: I am aware of the blocking nature of pipes and the go code I gave runs fine. I'm suggesting a way to make non-blocking pipes that _store_ some amount of information rather than waiting for a receiver. My point with the go code is that the data channel buffers, i.e. stores information in the `data` channel so it doesn't _need_ to block. I'm asking if there's an equivalent with Unix that uses a similar technique.

Comment: @stackoverflowuser I thought my answer clearly answered that: you cannot do this with Unix pipes. Did you want to know more? If so, clearly state it in the question. If you were just looking at "another way to do this" well you can do this with files, memory buffers, and a thousand other things. It's a very broad question in such case.

Comment: I'll try to research a workaround... Thanks for your help!